# Google App Engine: A handler to delete 'any' entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

My entities can currently be viewed using the path `/12345` where 12345 represents its `entity ID`.

I want to create a handler which deletes any entity using `/12345/delete`.

The handler would look something like this:

```
class DeleteHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, entity_id):
       # cannot retrieve entity using just entity_id
       # We cannot use KIND.get_by_id(entity_id), since 'entity kind' is unknown
```

How can we get the entity kind using the url, so that we may use `get_by_id()` to retrieve the entity, and then delete it?

Am I approaching this correctly? Or is there a better way?

Comment: So the `/12345/delete` any entity with id 12345?

Comment: Yes sir - that's correct @JimmyKane

Comment: It doesn't feel right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity ids are not unique across kinds, so I don't really know how you are expecting this to work.

The websafe encoded version of the full key, however, does give enough information to uniquely identify the entity. You can then use that to instantiate a key, and you can call delete on that key.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't feel right.

I would go simply with `kind/12345/delete`

To answer your question, one approach could be with whitelisting.

Set somewhere the `kinds` (classes) you want this operation to delete their objects (entities).

Suppose you have these Kinds:

```
class Foo(ndb.Expando):
  pass


class Boo(ndb.Expando):
  pass


class Bar(ndb.Expando):
  pass
```

Now since you have the id:

```
kinds_to_delete = ['Foo', 'Boo', 'Bar']
for kind_to_delete in kinds_to_delete:
  ndb.Key(kind_to_delete, entity_id).delete()
```

Or as a dirty oneliner:

`[ndb.Key(kind, entity_id).delete() for kind in ['Foo', 'Boo', 'Bar']]`

Answer (score 0):

```
/<key>/delete
```

Maybe it's easier if you passed around the base64 representation of the key